How to geometrically prove/show the the gradient vector is perpendicular to the level curve/surface?
I have understood how to use the algebraic method to prove that the gradient vector is perpendicular to the level set of a function of n-variables. But I am just wondering how to show that geometrically in the level surface/curve.
For example, in a function of two variables (that means we are talking about level curves)
$$\nabla f(x_0,y_0) = f_x(x_0,y_0)i+f_y(x_0,y_0)j$$
Since $f_x(x_0,y_0)$  and $f_y(x_0,y_0$ are just two numbers, so how to show it geometrically that using these two numbers as the coefficients of $i$ and $j$ will produce a vector that is perpendicular to the level curve?

I am just wondering whether there is a graph or something that can vividly illustrate the relationship between the gradient vector and the level set. Since it is very weird if I think the partial derivative as just numbers and combine them together, you will get a new vector that is perpendicular to the level curve/surface (In lower dimensions)

Sry, I refer to the comment that hasn't been edited just now. As I have mentioned, let's talk about the function of two variables, in this case, the level curve is in $\R^2$ and now the gradient vector is also a vector in $\R^2$ (I think this is obvious)
For "you will get a new vector", I am sorry for causing confusion, what I mean is using this two "coefficients" (from the partial derivatives), we can form only a gradient vector at this point (only one at this point). But if your point is changed, the gradient vector may change. So it may have other gradient vectors (in numeric form)

As you have spoken of level curves, I shall stick to that analogy. First I shall assume here that the $f$ function has all required properties, say for example that it is $C^1$.
When you follow a level curve on a real terrain, you go neither upper nor lower, but stay at the same height by definition of a level curve. The shorter distance to climb up one meter or go down one (when the level curves are smooth enough) is to go away from the level curve with a right angle. Because the level curves are locally parallel straight lines. That is exactly what the gradient represents...

If I'm understanding correctly what you're asking, I would proceed using definition of a curve in a three dimensional space, gradient of a multivariable function and implicit function theorem. I would go with two variables for simplicity but it's extendable with a bit of work

We want to show that a level curve $\gamma$ of a function $f(x,y)$ is perpendicular to $\nabla f$ so this means
$$\color{red}{\gamma '} \cdot \color{blue}{\nabla f} = 0 \label{eq1}\tag{1}$$
we know that the gradient $\nabla f = (\partial_xf, \partial_yf)$, how about the red part? Is the tangent vector of our level curve this means a curve defined via
$$f(x,y) = k, \quad k\in \Bbb R \label{eq2}\tag{2}$$
Here we implicitly defined a curve but I want an explicit definition so I fix a point $(x_0,y_0)$ inside function's domain and let $f(x_0,y_0) = 0$ (if not we can define $F(x,y) = f(x,y) - f(x_0,y_0)$ so it's not a big deal) and $\partial_y f(x_0,y_0) \neq 0$ then in a neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0)$ we have that locus of points $f = 0$ coincide with a function $\phi(x)$ and
$$\phi'(x) = -\frac{\partial _xf}{\partial_y f}\label{eq3}\tag{3}$$
this means that the curve $\gamma = (x,\phi(x))$ and $\eqref{eq1}$ could be rewritten as
$$\begin{align*}\bigg ( 1, -\frac{\partial _xf}{\partial_y f}\bigg)\cdot (\partial_x f, \partial_y f) &= \partial_xf -\frac{\partial _xf\partial_yf}{\partial_y f} \\
&= \frac{\partial_xf\partial_yf-\partial _xf\partial_yf}{\partial_y f} = 0
\end{align*} 
$$

Note I'm being a little bit let's say "quick" and this is not complete as an argument, for example why we could suppose $\partial_y f \neq 0$? $f(x,y) = k $ is a curve in a 3-D space so why its tangent vector is 2-D and other small liberties I took in tackling the problem. It's just something to get a gasp of what is happening, feel free to fill the gaps! Hope this helps!
